# Mule 3.3 Datamapper xsd cannot be found when running mvn test

Tags: mule

I am currently using Mule EE and it works fine there (I skip the tests so that I can build the binary) but once I run mvn test I get a SaxParseException because it cannot find the schema definition. Here is the error I got.

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/data-mapper/current/mule-data-mapper.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not `<xsd:schema>`.

Comment: It looks like you don't have included the DataMapper dependency in your pom. Also for any EE feature (such as DM) i'd recommend you to contact MuleSoft.

Comment: The build made after mvn package works once run on the server though. As for the DM dependency, I don't see any jar to add except for mule-module-data-mapper.zip. Thanks though. Yep, since this is an EE feature, we are going to contact MuleSoft once the processing for the license finishes.

Comment: The problem is that during the package phase the mule config file won't be parsed, however if any test loads a mule config it will be needing the DM jar provided by stdio but not during maven lifecycle, triggering the exception. What version of mule are using?

Comment: I'm using the 1.3.1 Studio and 3.3.1 EE. Thanks for the response. The studio provides a zip actually. Not sure if it will behave the same by adding a zip dependency as compared to a jar.